# How to replace single quote in asp.net c#

Tags: c#

I used `Regex.Replace(jobdesc, @"[^\/\'-]+", " ");` but its not working please help me I want to replace only (' and -) with blank space how to arrange this regex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Reg Exp you can do as below

```
string pattern = @"\-\'";
    string input = "mynam-'is";
    string replacement = " ";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple replace like:

```
"your sentence".Replace("''"," ").Replace("-"," ");
```